# Is it possible to do a batch upsert on a MongoDB, and have it return the new, altered documents?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using `pymongo`, and I'd like to shrink the following process down to one/fewer Mongo calls.

Use case:

1. A client accesses my API endpoint.
2. My backend upserts some data to Mongo (affects ~10-100 documents)
3. My API returns the new, updated versions of each doc from collection to the client

Right now, all I've figured out is to do:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient(MONGO_URI)
db = client[MONGO_DB]
collection = db[MONGO_COLLECTION]

for doc in docs:
    collection.update({<doc id>},{<doc>}, upsert=True)

new = []
for doc in docs:
    new.append(collection.find({<doc id>})[0])

return new
```

This is the gist of my approach right now, and it feels incredibly wasteful. It seems like there should be a way to do this:

```
new = collection.update([<a whole bunch of documents], upsert=True)
return new.results  # or similar
```

Is it possible?

Comment: It is quite wasteful as bulk writes can be very efficient in that they are **one** request and response and not hundreds, or thousands.I think you need to "rethink" your design approach here and what you are doing. I fail to see any useful application where you would **need** to send even 100's of responses back to a "client" or even have any sort of interactive request that generates that many updates. Bulk update activity is usually the realm of autmation processes, hence the lack of visibility of changes from the human end. Sounds like "premature optimization" to me.

Comment: @BlakesSeven maybe you're right, but I can't see a different solution. I have products represented by `docs` in a `collection`. A client issues one request, the backend wants to give client ~50 products from db, but it needs to first update all of the docs with new info that it gets from it's own API call elsewhere. So the backend calls an external API, gets the appropriate list of docs it will need to return, upserts those docs to my DB, returns to client the version that equals API version + my `db`'s version together. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Again. Cannot think of a valid use case. This would be way to broad for a single question but it sounds something like fetching inventory amounts, adjusting them for the amounts removed and sending to the client. In which case the "client" **should** be totally oblivious to such information and just be concerned with the list of items, therefore not needing any updates, even if they happen somewhere else, and not necessarily within the request. Like I said, way to broad and I'm likely way off the mark since it's not in front of me.

Comment: A design rethink does seem in order. Try asking small questions about different parts of the implemented solution you have. Others may give you a fresh perspective. But if you are demanding updating 100's of documents and returning the modified result for each, then it's just not optimal, and you already have what you get from that. And likely to get worse.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I'm open to ur ideas. I just need a user to be able to do a search for products, and before I send them back, I need to get them from an external API, update my products in the db, and send back info that came from the db, along with the newly fetched info. The data fetched from the external API dictates the product ids that I need to return, as well as other info abt the products I need to aggregate with the records from the database. Any ideas on how to simplify things?